# Every time when I start R or want to compile a PDF via knitr I get the following message

Tags: r, ssl

The message pops up every time I open R and I still can run code, but it won't let me compile PDFs via knitr. What causes this message and how can I get rid of it? I run R on a Mac btw.

[image]

Comment: Looks more like an Rstudio error. I suggest you delete your `.Rdata` file.

Comment: can you see the mentiond file tst.rnw? you could search for `sslmode='require'` in your project (STRG + Shift + F)

Comment: I deleted the `.Rdata` file, which did not help and searched for `sslmode='require'`, which did not result in a finding. I think this problem is related to me trying to set up some kind of connection to download financial data into R.